# Not getting all the elements of an array Visual C++

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files

I'm trying to add the elements from a text file to an array ,I used strtok() in order to split them and then tried to add them into the array,but for some reason the program is showing me only the first element.I've tried every possible combination of for and while but still not managed to solve it and get all the elements .
The input:Dan , 19 , male , 1.80 , 80 , normal , active , mentinere , normal
EDIT:after I changed the code the program will print 7 times "Dan" .
Here is the code after the edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("text.txt");
    char* user;
    user = new char[10];
    
    char sep[] =",";
    while (f>>user) {
        string v[8];

        
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {char* p = strtok(user, sep);
            v[i] = p;
        
            while (p != NULL)
            {


                p = strtok(NULL, sep);

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            cout << v[i] ;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `user = new char;` do you what that does? How much memory will it allocate? There's a reason why the overload for reading to `char *` was removed from the standard.

Comment: `user = new char;` is only allocating space (on the heap - strange) for 1 character

Comment: `char* v[10];  *v = new char;` is also very strange  please stop using c-arrays and start using `std::string`, `std::vector` etc - ie 10 year old C++.

Comment: Have you tried C++? I know that's facetious, but `std::string` and its own class member functions might be better suited.

Comment: Unrelated: There is no need to make `f` a global variable. Open it in the narrowest scope possible and it'll close itself when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read CSV file".  There are already a plethora of issues and examples of reading a comma separated file (CSV), including a bunch on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of the input.

Comment: Do you know what `f >> user` does? Are you using a Debugger? But more important, you asked a question, why don't you care about answering to the people trying to help you?

Comment: I use the f>>user to read the data from the text file ,and I really care about the people trying to help me and try to use every advice they give me , I am sorry if it looked like I didn't ,and thanks for all the support so far

Comment: @AURAS I realize my message was a little to harsh. Sorry about that. With your input (a file containing exactly `Dan , 19 , male , 1.80 , 80 , normal , active , mentinere , normal`) what will `f >> user` read?

Comment: I hope I m not wrong ,if i use f>>user it will read the whole line until it reaches the last element from that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that the structure suggests that you want to read a line and then tokenize it with `strtok`. Unfortunately `f >> user` (with `user` being a `char*`) is the equivalent of `fscanf(f, "%s", user)`<sup>1</sup>, which tells the parser to skip any whitespace and then read any character stopping as soon as it finds a space.
So the first loop reads only `Dan` and later the inner loop tries to parse it (failing as described in Joseph Larson answer).

So, let's try to make your code work. First of all, it doesn't compile on my machine, since you are including `<string.h>` instead of just `<string>`.

Then don't put `using std::cout;` and `using std::string;` at file level, but just inside functions, or even better avoid them as much as possible.

Then stop using `char*` and `new` and switch to `std::string`.

Then exchange `f >> user` with `getline(f, user)` (notice that this is the free standing function, not the method of the std::string class). This will read a full line that you will be able to tokenize.

Your loop is really off. You could do it like:

```
        int i = 0;
        char* p = strtok(&user[0], sep);
        while (i < 8 && p != NULL) {
            v[i] = p;
            ++i;
            p = strtok(NULL, sep);
        }
```

Finally the print loop has a off by one error and doesn't print the last word.

The total program becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("text.txt");
    std::string user;

    char sep[] = ",";
    while (getline(f, user)) {
        std::string v[8];

        int i = 0;
        char* p = strtok(&user[0], sep);
        while (i < 8 && p != NULL) {
            v[i] = p;
            ++i;
            p = strtok(NULL, sep);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            std::cout << v[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that you should be learning more C++ and less old style C libraries. An interesting method to check is `std::string::find_first_of()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course `f` should be a `FILE*` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ,it helped me understand better then the actual teacher ,and i can just hope that someday I will drop those old c styles and use c++ properly.

Answer (score 0):

This loop is flawed:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {char* p = strtok(user, sep);
        v[i] = p;
    
        while (p != NULL)
        {


            p = strtok(NULL, sep);

        }
    }
```

What you really want to do is something like this:

```
   for (int index = 0, char *p = strtok(user, sep); index < 7 && p != nullptr; ++index, p = strtok(nullptr, sep)) {
       v[index] = p;
   }
```

Your inner loop is almost right in that you're calling strtok properly, but you're not storing it anywhere. And you don't need a nested loop.

Comment: thank you so much ,I ll try to implement it right away